# Siege - How to test views that require login?

Tags: django, stress-testing, siege

I am trying to use Siege to do stress testing on my django application. For static pages (e.g. landing page) it works just fine. However, 99% of the pages I want to test require that I be logged in.

How can I get Siege to login and test django views? The login page uses the Django Login form and view.

Answer (score 1):

If it possible to test as one user logined in you can pass session cookie as Cookie header -H "Cookie: cookieValue". For more complicated scenario better to Apache Jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

For basic HTTP authentication form, adding `login=SomeUsername:somepassword` to *siege.conf* directives worked for me. May be possible to use for other login schemes.